# Rendering html entities in webforms DropDownList control

Tags: drop-down-menu, webforms, html-select, html-entities

I am trying to use html entities in in a DropDownList control.  The reason I am using entities is because I want to display units with superscripts such as m²/s or kg/m³.  sup is not an option because it doesn't work inside a select option tag.  I have created a small example that illustrates my problem.  Here is my aspx page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head runat="server">
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
</head>

<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            <select>           
                <option value="1">M&#179;/min</option>
                <option value="2">M&#179;/s</option>
            </select>

            <asp:DropDownList ID="drp" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>


        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

and here is my code behind:

```
public partial class MyPage: System.Web.UI.Page
{
    private class idAndUnit
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Unit { get; set; }
    }


    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var units = new List<idAndUnit>()
        {
            new idAndUnit
            {
                Id = 1,
                Unit = "M&#179;/min"
            },
            new idAndUnit
            {
                Id = 2,
                Unit = "M&#179;/min"
            }
        };


        drp.DataSource = units;
        drp.DataTextField = "Unit";
        drp.DataValueField = "Id";
        drp.DataBind();


    }
}
```

If you run the page and look at the source html it generates you see the following:

```
<select>           
    <option value="1">M&#179;/min</option>
    <option value="2">M&#179;/s</option>
 </select>

 <select name="drp" id="drp">
    <option value="1">M&amp;#179;/min</option>
    <option value="2">M&amp;#179;/min</option>
```

As you can see the DropDownList version has changed M³/min into M&#179;/min.I'm not sure why this change happens presumably either to be helpful in some way or perhaps a security reason for preventing xss or something like that.  Is it possible to prevent this behaviour here so I can get the output I'm after?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just figured it out

using HttpUtility.HtmlDecode("M³/min") fixes it.